# ImageJ Macro not running to completion after called from powershell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, vbscript, imagej

This project has a bunch of moving parts working together but I have come up with a minimal working example for the purposes of this post.  Here is what I am trying to do:

1. have a powershell script waiting for a .xlsx file to be created in a directory
2. when a file is created, the script launches an imageJ macro
3. the imageJ macro calls for a VBscript to run
4. the VBscript calls for an excel macro to run
5. after the excel macro runs, control returns to the imageJ macro which finishes and displays a message

What works:

- the powershell script is able to detect new .xlsx files being created
- the imageJ macro launches which in turn launches the .vbs script
- the excel macro runs to completion when called by .vbs
- the process runs perfectly when started from imageJ macro and not from powershell

Issues:

- the ImageJ macro does not run to completion after calling the vbs script
- ImageJ macro repeatedly called by powershell even when only 1 new file was created

I realize this is probably the most inefficient way to accomplish the task needed but below are the code snippets from each platform:

Powershell Script:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\yourMachine\Desktop"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.xlsx*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$path"
                Clear-content "C:\Users\yourMachine\Desktop\log.txt"
                Add-content "C:\Users\yourMachine\Desktop\log.txt" -value $logline
                cd "C:\Users\yourMachine\Desktop\Fiji.app"
                ./ImageJ-win64 --ij2 --headless --console --run C:\Users\yourMachine\Desktop\Fiji.app\scripts\example.ijm
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while($true) {sleep 5}
```

ImageJ macro:

```
exec("cscript.exe \"C:\\Users\\yourMachine\\Desktop\\example.vbs")

"Hello world!";
```

VBscript:

```
Option Explicit

example

Sub example()

Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook

Set  xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")   

xlApp.visible = True
set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\yourMachine\Desktop\example.xlsm", 0)
xlApp.Run xlBook.name & "!Module1.addNumbers"
xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Excel Macro:

```
Sub addNumbers()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6"
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "7"
    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "8"
    Range("A9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "9"
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10"
    Range("A11").Select
End Sub
```

I really appreciate any help or insight on how I can make this work/more efficient than its current state.  I am new to all of these languages and do not understand much of the background talking between them that is going on here.  Thanks!